# Probability $P(X < Y)$ given $\mu_X, \mu_Y,\sigma_X^2, \sigma_Y^2$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Let $X, Y$ two independent random variables so that $0 \leq X,Y \leq 1$ . The mean and variance of $X, Y$ are denoted by $\mu_X, \mu_Y,\sigma_X^2, \sigma_Y^2$.

Is this enough information to estimate/bound non-trivially the probability $P(X < Y)$?

Comment: Given the Gaussian random variables $X$, $Y$ with known mean and variance, how can we find the joint distribution of the pair $(X, Y)$?

Comment: @hyperkahler, but they are not Gaussian, I'd wish to not assume the distribution of them.